# How to set the focus on a materialbutton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the focus the focus on the material button so I can press enter or click the button an create an item

```
final FocusNode _createButtonFocusNode = new FocusNode();

@override
void initState() {
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_createButtonFocusNode);
   super.initState();
}
 RawKeyboardListener(
                focusNode: _createButtonFocusNode,
                onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
                  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                    _createItem();
                  }
                },
child:RaisedButton(focusNode: _createButtonFocusNode,
                 onPressed: () {
                      _createItem();
                    },
                    child: Text("Create"))))
```

Assume also a cancel material button exists with a _cancelItem event that should be able to accept an enter key on focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `_node.requestFocus()` to request focus and list keyboard event with `FocusAttachment` and `attach` 
In demo code, when receive `Enter` will change button color, see working demo below 
code snippet

```
_node.requestFocus();
...
FocusAttachment _nodeAttachment;
 _nodeAttachment = _node.attach(context, onKey: _handleKeyPress);
...
 bool _handleKeyPress(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
      print('Focus node ${node.debugLabel} got key event: ${event.logicalKey}');
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
        print('clicked enter');
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.deepPurple;
        });
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
// Flutter code sample for FocusNode

// This example shows how a FocusNode should be managed if not using the
// [Focus] or [FocusScope] widgets. See the [Focus] widget for a similar
// example using [Focus] and [FocusScope] widgets.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  FocusNode focusNode;
  CustomButton({Key key, this.focusNode}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState();
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
  bool _focused = false;
  FocusAttachment _nodeAttachment;
  Color _color = Colors.white;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //widget.focusNode = FocusNode(debugLabel: 'Button');
    widget.focusNode.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
    _nodeAttachment = widget.focusNode.attach(context, onKey: _handleKeyPress);
  }

  void _handleFocusChange() {
    print(widget.focusNode.hasFocus);
    if (widget.focusNode.hasFocus != _focused) {
      setState(() {
        _focused = widget.focusNode.hasFocus;
        _color = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }

  bool _handleKeyPress(FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
    if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
      print('Focus node ${node.debugLabel} got key event: ${event.logicalKey}');
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
        print('clicked enter');
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.deepPurple;
        });
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.focusNode.removeListener(_handleFocusChange);
    // The attachment will automatically be detached in dispose().
    widget.focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _nodeAttachment.reparent();
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        focusNode: widget.focusNode,
        color: _focused ? _color : Colors.white,
        child: Text(_focused ? "focused" : 'Not focus'),
        onPressed: () {
          print("create item");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatelessWidgetState createState() => _MyStatelessWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatelessWidgetState extends State<MyStatelessWidget> {
  FocusNode _node1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _node2 = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: textTheme.headline4,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CustomButton(
            focusNode: _node1,
          ),
          CustomButton(
            focusNode: _node2,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _node1.requestFocus();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("request focus button 1")),
          RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _node2.requestFocus();
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("request focus button 2")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Suppose you have an create button and a cancel button.  If you tab and press enter will the code know which event to call - create or cancel?  In your code sample, you assuming only one focus state for a single material button

Comment: I have update full code and working demo. you can check it. you can pass focus node.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is for the button to be focused by default, you can do that by just specifying `autofocus:true` on the button, and you don't even need to create a `FocusNode`:

```dart
class MyCustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void _createItem() {
    print('Item created');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      autofocus: true,
      child: const Text('CREATE'),
      onPressed: _createItem,
    );
  }
}
```

This will automatically focus the widget when first built, as long as something else doesn't have the focus already.

If you need to set the focus from another control, you can do that with a focus node, but you don't need to use a `FocusAttachment` (you rarely, if ever, need to use one of those), you can just pass it to the button and call `requestFocus()` on it.

```dart
class MyCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomWidget> createState() => _MyCustomWidgetState();
}

class _MyCustomWidgetState extends State<MyCustomWidget> {
  late FocusNode _createButtonFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createButtonFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _createButtonFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _createItem() {
    print('Item created');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,      
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('FOCUS OTHER BUTTON'),
            onPressed: () => _createButtonFocusNode.requestFocus(),
          ),
          TextButton(
            focusNode: _createButtonFocusNode,
            child: const Text('CREATE'),
            onPressed: _createItem,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(When you do create a `FocusNode`, be sure to dispose of it properly.)

Comment: For more information on the subject, we've recently [published a guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/focus) on using focus in Flutter on the official Flutter website.